# iOS View Into Android

Tags: android, ios, tableview, listactivity

I have an iOS app deployed and now I'm developing its version for Android. Since i dont have much experience with the Android different widgets I'm having trouble figuring whats the best approach to develop a certain iOS view into Android.

The question is, using Android own tools, what would be the best approach to develop the following iOS view into Android? Note that i want to use only Android own tools, i have seen some grouped UITableView developed for Android and hosted on GitHub, but i dont want that.

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the too broaden question.. but im an iOS user and never used an Android device before, so i dont really know what are the most used widgets for this kind on interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That orange bar with the text "Perfil" is called [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) and its buttons are created with the [onCreateOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) method.

The background is a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) (or a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)).

The photo is an [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html).

Those black texts are [TextViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) and the brown ones are [EditTexts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html) in a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html).

And the bar at the bottom is a [TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabWidget.html).

Comment: Yes, but don't but tabs at the bottom as many Android devices have the home and back buttons there and it's easy to catch one of them when UI navigation elements are at the bottom.  I know, I've got a Galaxy and apps that mimic iOS are a pain in the ^Y*$*%"

Comment: Yes, I suggest to put the tabs below the ActionBar.

Comment: Yes @Dehumanizer actually my question is regarding only the android substitute for the grouped table view in iOS.. i got the tabs at the top and stuff.. but for the table, should i use a ListView and create different rows xmls for them or should i use a ScrollView and just user relative layout for the subviews or something else?

Comment: also, what would be an elegant way to separate the data i need to display? in iOS i had the table separated in groups and each group had a title (the header view)... but what would be the best approach or the most common one for this kind of view? thanks

Comment: Use ListView. Working with ScrollView in this case will be very painful. It is a good tutorial about ListView: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html.

Comment: Really useful tutorial, started reading it already! So even if the rows of the table that i implemented in the iOS app wont be clickable and wont be editable, it only shows data, you suggest me to use ListView? I was starting to think that ScrollView with a reltive layout wouldnt be so bad..

Answer (score 3):

The best answer is the one by `Dehumanizer`. But you should also remember that each OS has it's own look and feel, and if you mix them, your app might be seen poorly designed and ultimately it may confuse users.

Always read the Android design guide before designing an Android layout: http://developer.android.com/design/index.html

Comment: Yep.. i know that, and i actually said something about it in the question.. se my comment for @Dehumanizer's answer